# HTML dropdown in one line

Tags: html, css, salesforce

How can I bring three drop down menus in one line. I want to bring my day, month and year in one line but coudln't do so. Any help would be appreciable. I am attaching my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y8phssbp/1/).

```
<form action=
        "https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToCase?encoding=UTF-8"
        method="post">
            <input name="orgid" type="hidden" value="">
            <input name="retURL" type="hidden" value="">
....
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

just add `#day, #month, #birthyear{ display:inline-block;}`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y8phssbp/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Adding empty `<label>` tags should do the trick. **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/y8phssbp/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Link is missing in your question so I could not point exactly to the solution but try below code. Hope this meets your requirement.

```
<html>
<head>
   <style>
   * {
font-family: Arial;
font-size:12px;
}
.setDate {
position:relative;
padding:20px;
}
.dateContainer {
width:400px;
display:none;
position:absolute;
top:40px;
left:20px;
background: #ffffff;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
padding:10px;
}
.dateContainer .form-field {
display:inline-block;
margin-top: 10px;
}
</style>
   <script>
        $('#finalDate').focus(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id'),
     cVal = $(this).val(),
     cY = cVal.substr(6, 4),
     cM = cVal.substr(0, 2),
     cD = cVal.substr(3, 2),
     d = new Date(),
     y = d.getFullYear() + 1;
    setYears(1900, y);
    $('#ChangeDate').clone().insertAfter($(this));
    $(this).siblings('.dateContainer').find('#sYear').val(cY);
    $(this).siblings('.dateContainer').find('#sMonth').val(cM);
    $(this).siblings('.dateContainer').find('#sDay').val(cD);
    $(this).siblings('.dateContainer').show();
    setDate(id);
   });

var setDate = function (id) {
 $('.SetDate').click(function () {
     var y = $('#sYear option:selected').val(),
         m = $('#sMonth option:selected').val(),
         d = $('#sDay option:selected').val(),
         date = m + '/' + d + '/' + y;
     $('#' + id).val(date);
     $(this).parents('.dateContainer').remove();
 });
 $('.CancelDate').click(function () {
     //$('#' + id).val(date);
     $(this).parents('.dateContainer').remove();
 });
}

var setYears = function (sRange, eRange) {
 for (var i = sRange; i < eRange; i++) {
     $('#sYear').append('<option value"' + i + '">' + i + '</option>');
 };

 for (var i = 1; i <= 31; i++) {
     $('#sDay').append('<option value"' + i + '">' + i + '</option>');
 };

 }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="setDate">
<label for="StartDate">Date:</label>
<input class="form-control col-lg-5" name="StartDate" type="text" id="finalDate"     value="12/31/2013" />
</div>
  <div id='ChangeDate' class="dateContainer">
  <div class="form-field col-lg-5">
    <label for="sYear">Year:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="sYear" name="sYear" style="width:100px"></select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-field col-lg-5">
    <label for="sMonth">Month:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="sMonth" name="sMonth">
        <option value="1">Jan</option>
        <option value="2">Feb</option>
        <option value="3">Mar</option>
        <option value="4">Apr</option>
        <option value="5">May</option>
        <option value="6">Jun</option>
        <option value="7">Jul</option>
        <option value="8">Aug</option>
        <option value="9">Sep</option>
        <option value="10">Oct</option>
        <option value="11">Nov</option>
        <option value="12">Dec</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-field col-lg-2">
    <label for="sDay">Day:</label>
    <select id="sDay" name="sDay" class="form-control"></select>
</div>
<div class="form-field col-lg-12 text-right"> 
    <a href="#" class="CancelDate btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
    <a href="#" class="SetDate btn btn-default">Set Date</a>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```